# Is there an equivalent of the "in" function from Python in C++?

Tags: c++, python

I've mostly only dealt in Python programming as of late and their is a very useful built-in Function called "'in'

'in' allows you to access all of the elements in a variable.

For instance;

```
def main():
y = ["Yes", "yes", "YES",]
n = ["No", "no", "NO"]
print "yes or no?\n"
response = raw_input()
if response in y:
    print "Wonderful, your response was ", response, "\n"
    exit(0)
if response in n:
    print "Alas, your response was ", response, "\n"
    exit(0)
else:
    print "Message not read; please attempt again.\n"
    main()

main()
```

As you can see it uses the 'in' function to check through the strings in the dictionary.

I was wondering if there was an equivalent to this function in the standard C++ Library?

Comment: `std::unordered_set` may have this.

Comment: Changed title to C++ because you use C++ in question and in tags. Please re-edit and change to C everywhere if I'm wrong

Answer (score 3):

There is function

```
std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), needle) != std::end(a)
```

where `a` is array or `std::vector` or `std::list`

but in this case you may also use `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`. (And you should do it if there are quite many elements)

```
s.find(needle) != s.end()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the ways the others mentioned already, there's also [std::binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) which is arguably badly named. It returns true if an element exists and false otherwise. You need a **sorted container** to use it tho.

`bool found = std::binary_search(std::begin(container), std::end(container), element);`

Comment: The `std::binary_search()` function will only succeed if the container is sorted first!

Comment: @DietrichEpp Got that in the answer already. Think I'll make it bold for clarification tho.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ vectors:

```
if (std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), yourItem)!=vector.end() )
....
```

would be the equivalent of

```
if yourItem in vector:
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of `std` containers have a function called `find`. However, to get actual performance, you'll want to use `std::unordered_set` (C++11), as this uses a hashtable in the underlying implementation, making the `find()` operation in constant time, while other containers do it in linear time.

Comment: Note that Python list-find (as in the OP's example) is also a linear search.  (To get Python to use a hash table you put things in its dictionary type.)

Comment: I believe for 3 elements of lengths no more that 3 as in example difference isn't very big